# How can I grab this second media:thumbnail node from this xm file?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml list that looks like this but with more items:

```
<item>
      <title>Arrests over Dhaka building collapse</title>
      <description>blabla.</description>
      <link>http://url.com</link>
      <pubDate>Sat, 27 Apr 2013 14:56:50 GMT</pubDate>
      <media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://news.com/bla2.jpg" />
      <media:thumbnail width="144" height="81" url="http://news.com/bla.jpg" />
</item>
```

As you can see I have 2x media:thumbnails I want to always grab the last one that have 144 width and 81 height and never the first one. Its the img url I want to fill a variable with.

This is my code:

```
var url = "http://news.com";
            XNamespace dcM = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(url);
            var items = xdoc.Descendants("item")
            .Select(item => new
            {
                Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                Description = item.Element("description").Value,
                Link = item.Element("link").Value,
                PubDate = item.Element("pubDate").Value,
                Myimage= (string)item.Element(dcM + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value

            })
            .ToList();
```

This code gives me random thumbnails sometimes it gives me the first one and sometimes the second one. I always want the last thumbnail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is *not* a namespace issue :)

Comment: You're welcome...I'm hoping to have a solution for you here shortly as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the specific image you're interested in within your overall LINQ statement by only grabbing the `thumbnail` that has the attributes you're looking for.  I would suggest going based on attributes, in case there's more than 2 images or they change the order.

```
 var items = xdoc.Descendants("item")
                 .Select(item => new
                 {
                     Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                     Description = item.Element("description").Value,
                     Link = item.Element("link").Value,
                     PubDate = item.Element("pubDate").Value,
                     MyImage = item.Elements("thumbnail").Where(i => i.Attribute("width").Value == "144" && i.Attribute("height").Value == "81").Select(i => i.Attribute("url").Value).SingleOrDefault()
                 })
                 .ToList();
```

This line:

```
MyImage = item.Elements(dcM + "thumbnail")
               .Where(i => i.Attribute("width").Value == "144" && i.Attribute("height").Value == "81")
               .Select(i => i.Attribute("url").Value)
               .SingleOrDefault()
```

Will grab all the `thumbnail` elements for the current item, and select the one that has a width of 144 and a height of 81.

By the way, `Value` of `Attribute` returns a string, so you don't need to cast it.

**EDIT**

If you want the second one every time, and you don't care what the attributes are, you can use the following:

```
MyImage = item.Elements(dcM + "thumbnail").Skip(1).Take(1).Select(i => i.Attribute("url").Value).SingleOrDefault()
```

That uses the `Skip` and `Take` extension methods to grab the second one.

Comment: This is of course just an assumption, but I think he just wants to make sure to get the larger thumbnail. I would suggest just doing an OrderByDescending(x => x.Width).First() instead.

Comment: hmm im recieving Error 1 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Myimage' and no extension method 'Myimage' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?